# IntelliJ i18n-support for angular-translate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, angular-translate, angular-i18n

For Java Property Files we have the nice [Resource-Bundle Editor support in Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/editing-resource-bundle.html).

My question: Is there a plugin or settings to have the same side-by-side editing for JSON property files that are used by angular-translate?

They are basically key-value files, and the naming of the files is very close ("locale-en.json", "locale-fr.json").

Comment: For others: I did not find an option in IntelliJ, but then instead used this standalone applicaton: https://github.com/jcbvm/i18n-editor

Comment: There is a new plugin on the Marketplace: Easy I18n. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16316-easy-i18n 
-- looks promising, but I think it's still under development

Comment: @leo Just tried the plugin, it looks usable. It resorts your keys and does some reformatting, but looks promising. If you add it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I found is TransPlug:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8230-transplug

Personally like more the Resource Bundle view , but is something:

[Image of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAdQm.png)